# What's the max latency for OpenAI models accessed via Azure with provisioned throughput units?

Tags: openai, azure, latency

I'm currently using pay-as-you-go on Azure OpenAI and I'm curious to see how switching to provisioned throughput units would improve the latency.

I [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/provisioned-throughput):

> Predictable performance: stable max latency and throughput for uniform workloads.

What's the max latency for OpenAI models accessed via Azure with provisioned throughput units?